# using Object.prototype.toString function with undefined and null

Tags: javascript, object, types, null, undefined

I'm currently studying javascript's `Object.prototype.toString` method.

In the [MDN reference page on Object.prototype.toString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), it mentioned

> Note: Starting in JavaScript 1.8.5 toString() called on null returns
>   [object Null], and undefined returns [object Undefined], as defined in
>   the 5th Edition of ECMAScript and a subsequent Errata.

So

```
var a = undefined;
Object.prototype.toString.call(a); //chrome prints [object Undefined]

var b = null;
Object.prototype.toString.call(b); //chrome prints [object Null]
```

But I thought both `null` and `undefined` are primitive types with no corresponding wrapper type (unlike e.g. `string` primitive type and `String` object wrapper), so why is `[object Null]` and `[object Undefined]` printed when in fact null and undefined are not object.

And also, I thought with code like `Object.prototype.toString.call(a)`, it is the same as `a.toString()` (i.e. use `a` as the `this` inside `toString()` function), but when I tried

```
var a = undefined;
a.toString();
```

Chrome prints an error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

My thinking is that `undefined` is not in any way prototype-linked to `Object.prototype`, that's why `a.toString()` failed, but how come `Object.prototype.toString.call(a)` succeeded?

Comment: `undefined` and `null` can't be accessed with `.`. `Object.prototype` can.

Comment: Just because a value is primitive doesn't mean it can't be passed as the `this` value of a function. Try doing `Object.prototype.toString.call(1)`

Comment: I guess its wrong to consider `Object.prototype.toString.call(a)`, where `a` could be anything, as equivalent to `a.toString()`. Maybe its more correct to think of Object.prototype.toString.call(a) as setting the internal `this` property of Object.prototype.toString function to `a`.

Comment: Right. The `.call(a)` comes from [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), which describes the behavior of the `thisArg`. With non-strict functions, `undefined` and `null` would normally be changed to the global object (but `Object.prototype.toString` is a strict function).

Answer (score 1):

undefined is just that, undefined.  Null is treated as an object, but doesn't inherit any methods of the global object.

The reason you can call Object.prototype.toString.call on both of them and not undefined.toString or null.toString is the first is a simple function call.  The second is trying to call an object method, which neither has.  According to Mozilla, typeof null returns object "for legacy reasons".
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null

```js
var a;
console.log(typeof a);
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(a)); //chrome prints [object Undefined]
console.log(typeof Object.prototype.toString.call(a));

var b = null;
console.log(typeof b);
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(b)); //chrome prints [object Null]
console.log(typeof Object.prototype.toString.call(b));
```

Comment: `null` is not an object, and isn't treated as one either.

Comment: @Bergi when I say treated as an object, I mean in respect to the typeof operator. 
"In the first implementation of JavaScript, JavaScript values were represented as a type tag and a value. The type tag for objects was 0. null was represented as the NULL pointer (0x00 in most platforms). Consequently, null had 0 as type tag, hence the bogus typeof return value"
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof